# Regular expression to detect pre defined string codes or a group of these codes

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out how to detect some two digit string codes inside a bigger string, because it can have a code or two codes grouped by a `/`.

Example: I have these lines on a file and my regex don't get the first line, because it has `BL/DU`. It can have these codes `LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC` or one of these a slash and another one.

```
11645772  - . . - A NORA QUE A MAMAE PEDIU PRA DEUS BL/DU 11/12/2014
6437320  - . . - AMOR FATAL LB 25/06/2012 
5622777  - . . - AMOR QUE E MEU LB 16/08/2011 
5622778  - . . - AQUELA MAE LB 16/08/2011 
11645686  - . . - BALANCO DO MAR LB 11/12/2014
```

This is the regular expression i am using:

```
(\d+)\s+(-\s.\s.\s-)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+(LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC\/?LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `(...)` or `(?:...)` to group these alternatives and use an optional group for an optional `/` + code:

```
(\d+)\s+(-\s.\s.\s-)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+((?:LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC)(?:\/(?:LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC))?)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kx0dql/2)

*NOTE*: If the `.` in `(-\s.\s.\s-)` are to match literal dots, they must be escaped.

The change is here: `((?:LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC)(?:\/(?:LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC))?)`:

- `(?:LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC)` - matches one of the 2-letter codes
- `(?:\/(?:LB|BL|DU|HO|DP|DE|CO|EC))?` - optionally (due to the last `?` quantifier matching 1 or 0 occurrences) matches a `/` + the 2-letter code.

Comment: Also FYI: In some regex flavors, there is no support of non-capturing groups. In those cases, replace all `(?:` with `(`. In all other situations, consider using capturing `(...)` parentheses only when you need to access a submatch after a match is found, and use non-capturing `(?:...)` groups to just group alternatives/make some part of a pattern optional/when a part of a pattern repeats.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. It worked like a charm in PHP. I have also scaped the dots you pointed out.

Comment: Sometimes, people use `.` to match predefined format, where `.` or `/` or `-` can be found. So, I left it to you :). Glad to help.

Comment: i am having another problem on these matchings. I don't know if i have to make another question, but here it goes... 

I am using this regex to parse most of the content on the same file:
`(\d+)\s+([\.\w\s,'À-úÀ-ÿ()\?\-]+)\s+(?:(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?\s+)?(?:([\w\s]+)\s+)?(CA|C|V|AR)\s+(\d+,\d+)\s(\d+)`

But with some lines the #3 and #4 matches are being set on the #2. Here is some of the "bad" lines:
`33798 MARIA BETHANIA VIANNA TELLES VELOSO MARIA BETHANIA 008.81.39.83 UBC AR 0,00 3`
`1072551 JOERN DAHL 285.23.18.59 TONO AR 10,00 2`

Can you help with these?

Comment: If you use the regex on the contents of the whole file, and the contents contain multiple lines, and *you want to only find matches within a single line*, replace `\s` with `\h`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6J0b5c/2). `\h` only matches *horizontal* whitespace, `\s` matches *any* whitespace.

Comment: i am reading line by line, so this isn't the problem. On your demo groups 3 and 4 still are being set in group 2! I don't know why the numbers with dot are being caught with the name in group 2. :/

Comment: Are you looking for [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/6J0b5c/3)? `\w` also matches digits, so making it lazy will allow the engine to test the subsequent patterns first. Or just replace [`\w` with `[a-zA-Z_]`](https://regex101.com/r/6J0b5c/4).